# Dismissing a modal view controller with Search Bar cancel button

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, modalviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I've got a modal view controller with search bar and tableview, basically a pop-over search-box, presented using a pop-over segue. At the top it has a UISearchBar with a cancel button. I'm trying to dismiss the view controller using the cancel button on that search bar.

I tried quite a few approaches...

```
-(void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and delegate methods along the lines of

```
[self.delegate dismissModalViewController:self]
```

with

```
-(void) dismissModalViewController:(UIViewController*) viewToDismiss
{
    [viewToDismiss dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I don't know whether the UISearchBar is interfering but it seemed a reasonable hypothesis. Otherwise this is a common topic and I apologise for asking a question that may well have been answered before but I've read the fm and googled till I'm blue and still no results.

Comment: What happens when you hit cancel?

Comment: Make sure you set the search bar delegate to your presented view controller.

Comment: Nothing happens to the app. That said the delegates are properly set and the functions are all called.

Answer (score 16):

I experienced the same thing in a UIPopoverPresentationController within which I use a UISearchController to filter a tableview.

The **problem** is that the first time you call dismissViewController it dismisses the UISearchController, but there are no effects on the UI, so it's easy to think nothing happened. This is the UISearchBar interfering as you mention.

A **solution** is to call dismissViewController twice (I don't like this), or to call searchController.dismissViewController followed by self.dismissViewController.

Swift 3 example...

```
if searchController.isActive {
    searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 
        self.dismiss(animated: true) 
    })
} else {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe this was the solution...Thank you +1

Comment: Works great, thank you! It looks better to me if you set `animated: false` for searchController.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue and it's very frustrating that there doesn't seem to be a better way to solve this. I did this when dismissing the modal, not ideal but it's pretty smooth:

```
if(self.searchController.isActive){
    [self.searchController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.35 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    }];
}else{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```